How can I simply use the Youtube API to Upload Videos?
I produce Content that result in some Video-Files which I want to Schedule and "remember" the Upload-Date to Inform my Followers via Posts on Twitter etc.
So I have some processes that should Trigger as soon as a Video is live. And these processes are as of now manual, as I can't track all of the Schedules manually. This would be easier with automation and Uploads and/or Changes via API.
I once tried to do it via the Youtube API but had the well known Issue that You need to have your App reviewd with Data Protection Stuff available. But this seemed to be so much stuff for a simple and local running Youtube Manager for myself.
Is there an Option somewhere to restrict the Access to the API in a Way that it can only be used locally?
(I am not talking about Costs for the API, I am willing to pay for it. But I don't want to do this Data Protection Stuff for which I would need to have a public available Website and more relevant things)

Which programming language are you trying to use?

@kool I am using C# for programming.

Based on your requirements, it seems you're looking for a way to use the YouTube API for personal use without going through the extensive review process required for public applications. Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in way to restrict API access to local use only in the YouTube API.
However there is be a workaround for your needs:

You can use the YouTube Data API v3 with OAuth 2.0 authentication for your personal Google account.
This method allows you to create a project in the Google Developers Console and use the API without going through the verification process, as long as you're the only user.

Here's how you can set this up:

Go to the Google Developers Console.
Create a new project.
Enable the YouTube Data API v3 for your project.
Create OAuth 2.0 credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) for a desktop application.
Use these credentials in your application.

First of all you need a method to handle OAuth 2.0 authentication then you just need to add a method for uploading videos.
Here's a example how you can implement a YouTubeAPI class in python to include a video upload method:
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

class YouTubeAPI:

    def upload_video(self, file_path, title, description, category_id, privacy_status='private'):
        body = {
            'snippet': {
                'title': title,
                'description': description,
                'categoryId': category_id
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': privacy_status
            }
        }

        media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, resumable=True)

        request = self.youtube.videos().insert(
            part='snippet,status',
            body=body,
            media_body=media
        )

        response = request.execute()
        return response

Then you can add a new endpoint to handle video uploads.
This setup allows you to use the YouTube API for personal use without going through the extensive review process. However, keep in mind:

The API quota is limited for unverified apps.
This should only be used for personal projects where you're the only user.
You'll need to handle the OAuth flow manually

Include the necessary packages:
google-api-python-client
google-auth-oauthlib
google-auth-httplib2

as long as you're the only user of the application this solution can allow you to upload videos programmatically while avoiding the extensive review process. Good luck :)

But wont this result in forced private videos in my channel? Because like I said I tried this and all of the uploaded Videos were Private and couldn't be changed in Youtube Studio...
